# How can I recover content from an open source project host that has shut down?

Tags: codehaus, project-management, google-code

Codehaus shut down earlier this year. Many projects that were hosted there, including JIRA pages like [this one](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-131), are now broken.

What can I do to access all the lost content of projects that were hosted in Codehaus, such as bug reports? Was it uploaded/dumped somewhere?

Further, since Google Code is also shutting down, a similar problem will probably show up soon. What can be done to prevent the loss of important information like bug reports and wiki pages?

Comment: This post is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/q/14/20).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can recover that specific link via the way back machine:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150507060802/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-131

codehaus says from their termination page that you can redirect your projects:

> If you would like your projects links redirected then please see our redirector repository - create a sane squashed pull request and it will be added to the redirection system - you may add some 302s initially, but ultimately all redirects will be amended to 301s over time.

https://www.codehaus.org/termination/

In regards to google code shutting down, as well as codehaus, short term solution would be to switch to GitHub; however that poses the same problem(s)/risk(s) that you are running into now.

I'm a believer in owning your data - I would suggest setting up your repos on servers and domains that you own.

Comment: I don't see Github shutting down in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @TheSerenin: predictions “website X is going to last forever” can never be very reliable, except for virtually static, zero-maintenance sites. However I agree: github is just too perfect, I really can't think of any way it could become obsolete.

Comment: @leftaroundabout A way for Github to become obsolete is when version control systems (Git in particular) become obsolete. But as I said, I don't see that happening in the foreseeable future. I'm very sure however that something better will get around.

Comment: Github can shut down if they feel like it -- the great thing about Github is that I have a complete history of my repository locally, so I can reupload it to whatever replaces it as the the open-source-git-host.

Comment: @Gaurav sure they can, but why would they? They seem like the only hosting service that is doing great. They are profitable and they are expanding their team and they have some of the biggest technology-related companies using their product. I see no reason to shut it down any time soon. And unlike Google, hosting code is their only way of actually making money as a company.

Comment: no one thought sourceforge has any competitors...